# Prevent user from editing certain columns in a table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord Appointment model, which includes topic and time attributes. I would like to allow users to be able to modify time. But I want to prevent them from modifying topic after this field is populated.

How should I go about this cleanly in Rails?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a shared partial between your new and edit views, you can conditionally output an edit field for the columns in question if `appointment.is_new_record?` returns true. Otherwise, just render them as text.

Comment: rendering them as text will not stop someone from editing the form and forcing the value to get passed back.  This is the same issue Github recently had: http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/03/hacker-commandeers-github-to-prove-vuln-in-ruby.ars

Answer (score 0):

YOu should use attr_accessible in your model: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

This will mean on your create, you will have to manually set the value, but on your update, you can use mass assignment and any value not in the attr_accessible list will be ignored.

Comment: Hi Ben, I need to allow them to set the topic when they first create the appointment though

Comment: right so you would need to do something like m = Model.new(params[:model]); m.topic = params[:model][:topic], m.save in your create method.  Then in your update, you can just use m.update_attributes(params[:model]) with our fear of the topic value getting set (assuming you add attr_accessible :time in your model)